# ignore the value of IntSequenceGenerator in JSON response

Tags: json, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jackson, jackson-databind

I have used @JsonIdentityInfo on my class to avoid Infinite Recursion as follows

```
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "id", scope = IseidaPerfile.class)
public class IseidaPerfile implements Serializable {}
```

It is fixed the issue and my JSON response looks goods

```
 {
        "id": 22,
        "id": 3,
        "literal": "Responsible",
        "permissions": [
            3,
            4,
            {
                "id": 23,
                "id": 6,
                "literal": "Show menu"
            },
            7,
            8,
            9,
            10,
            11,
            12,
            13,
            14,
            15,
            16,
            17,
            18,
            19
        ]
    }
```

But I want to ignore the unused ids from Permissions as  3, 4,7, ..... 18, 19? which generated by IntSequenceGenerator

Comment: How you could generate so much sophisticated `JSON` from an empty class? Could you please show class and example which recreates this `JSON`? It is really hard to guess what is going on. Also, duplicated `id` keys are not a good sign.